# how to exclude weekend from SQL query

Tags: sql

```
dbo.FiscalCalendar.WeekNum, 
                         dbo.FiscalCalendar.FYQtr, DATEDIFF (hh, [Case].Opened, ISNULL([Case].Closed,GETUTCDATE())) / 24 AS DaysOpen, CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, [Case].Opened, ISNULL([Case].Closed,GETUTCDATE())) / 24) > 4 THEN '5+ Days' WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, [Case].Opened, 
                         ISNULL([Case].Closed,GETUTCDATE())) / 24) between + 1  and (DATEDIFF(hh, [Case].Opened, 
                         ISNULL([Case].Closed,GETUTCDATE())) / 24) +3  THEN '1-4 Days' ELSE '0 Days' END AS Ageing,
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the weekday value of your date and exclude Saturdays and Sundays (7 and 1)

```
WHERE DATEPART(weekday, [Your Date Here]) NOT IN (1,7)
```

Comment: Subject to `datefirst` setting.